# Why does AR(1) model with a small coefficient exhibit faster mean-reversion than one with a greater coefficient (when |$\beta$|<1)?

Tags: time-series, mean-reversion

Suppose we have two mean-reverting AR(1) models, given by

$$X_{t}=\beta X_{t-1}+\epsilon_t,$$

where $|\beta|<1$.

How fast series reverts to its mean is determined by the coefficient $\beta$. As far as I know, greater $\beta$ implies faster mean reversion. However, I simulated two time series using AR(1) model given above with $\beta=0.1$ and $\beta = 0.9$. Presumably, the series with the coefficient of 0.9 should revert to the mean faster than the one with 0.1 coefficient. The plots below, however, suggest the opposite -- AR(1) with 0.1 coefficient is a faster mean-reverting process, than AR(1) with 0.9 coefficient. Why?
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you got the intuition backwards. The conditional expectation of $Y_t$ given $Y_{t-1}$ is $\beta Y_{t-1}$. That is, $\mathbb{E}(Y_t|Y_{t-1})=\beta Y_{t-1}$. (We used the fact that $\mathbb{E}(\epsilon_t|Y_{t-1})=0$.)
If $\beta$ is close to 1, $\mathbb{E}(Y_t|Y_{t-1})=\beta Y_{t-1}$ is close to $1\cdot Y_{t-1}=Y_{t-1}$, thus there is little mean reversion. The series stays close to where it was, on average.
If $\beta$ is close to 0, $\mathbb{E}(Y_t|Y_{t-1})=\beta Y_{t-1}$ is close to $0\cdot Y_{t-1}=0$, thus there is quick mean reversion. There series goes to zero (which is its long-term mean), on average.

Comment: I see, thank you very much. The confusing was that in Ornstein-Uhlenbeck framework, the bigger the mean-reversion coefficient, the greater the speed of reversion. Here, in AR it is the opposute.

Comment: @Sane, you are welcome :)

Comment: @Sane - the O-U stochastic differential equation has a negative sign before the "big==faster" coefficient $\theta$: $~dx_t = -\theta x_t dt + \sigma dW_t$.